# Why are different result between use date_part and exactly date parameter query data in peroid date?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm try to count distinct value in some columns in a table.
i have a logic and i try to write in 2 way
But i get diffent results from this two query.
Can any one help to clarify me? I dont know what wrong is code or i think.

SQL

```
select count(distinct membership_id) from members_membership m
where date_part(year,m.membership_expires)>=2019
and date_part(month,m.membership_expires)>=7
and date_part(day,m.membership_expires)>=1
and date_part(year,m.membership_creationdate)<=2019
and date_part(month,m.membership_creationdate)<=7
and date_part(day,m.membership_creationdate)<=1
;

select count(distinct membership_id) from members_membership m
where m.membership_expires>='2019-07-01'
and m.membership_creationdate<='2019-07-01'
;
```

Comment: its because date_part(month,m.membership_expires)>=7 will return all year with this month.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen there are three answer with same meaning, but when i accept there only one will be accept not all three. this is my first question. i dont know what is the effect when i accept one answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually think that this is the query you intend to run:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT membership_id)
FROM members_membership m
WHERE
    m.membership_expires >= '2019-07-01' AND
    m.membership_creationdate < '2019-07-01';
```

It doesn't make sense for a membership to expire at the same moment it gets created, so if it expires on midnight of 1st-July 2019, then it should have been created strictly before that point in time.

That being said, the problem with the first query is that, e.g., the restriction on the month being on or before July would apply to *every* year, not just 2019.  It is difficult to write a date inequality using the year, month, and day terms separately.  For this reason, the second version you used is preferable.  It is also sargable, meaning that an index on `membership_expires` or `membership_creationdate` can be used.

Comment: thank you for you answer, this is a clearly description for me
ps. i use this sql for check available  member or status member

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the first query:

```
select count(distinct membership_id) from members_membership m
where date_part(year,m.membership_expires)>=2019
and date_part(month,m.membership_expires)>=7
and date_part(day,m.membership_expires)>=1
and date_part(year,m.membership_creationdate)<=2019
and date_part(month,m.membership_creationdate)<=7
and date_part(day,m.membership_creationdate)<=1; -- do you think that any day is less than 1?? 
-- this condition will be satisfy by only 01-Jul-2019, But I think you need all the dates before 01-Jul-2019
```

`and date_part(day,m.membership_creationdate)<=1` is culprit of the issue.
even `membership_creationdate` = `15-jan-1901` will not satisfy above condition.

You need to always use date functions on date columns to avoid such type of issue. (Your second query is perfectly fine)

Cheers!!

Comment: I miss this point. my first query compare year, month and day of date not compare whole date.

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be due to a time component.

The proper comparison for the first query is:

```
select count(distinct membership_id)
from members_membership m
where m.membership_expires >= '2019-07-01' and
      m.membership_creationdate < '2019-07-02'
--------------------------------^ not <= ---^ next day
```

This logic should work regardless of whether or not the "date" has a time component.